# making WPF webbrowser not accessible for user

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, disabled-control

maybe it's quite easy question, but I haven't managed to find a solution. I'm using web browser only to display data, and don't want user to access shown webpage. I know that in win forms' webbrowser it's possible, but how can I achieve it using WPF control?

PS I don't want to lock browser action in the navigate event, as described here: [How can I make a WPF WebBrowser read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381492/how-can-i-make-a-wpf-webbrowser-read-only) , because this won't stop my user from running javascripts etc

PPS And I also don't want to disable js, because I want it to be used by webpages. What is more, I'm executing it from code, as long as navigating between sites

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What part of `WebBrowser` UI you want to limit? Right-click menu?

Comment: @Noseratio entire UI. In other words, I want to make browser read-only

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Windows_Loaded Event

```
webbrowser1.IsEnabled = false;
```