# How can I forbid mouse click links in web browser of my WPF application?

Tags: wpf, click, mouseevent

I developed a WPF application, in my application I added a webbrowser control, and then I want forbidden mouse click the links in web browser. I have tried like this:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="show_web" Canvas.Top="64" Width="900" Height="488" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="False" />
```

but it does not work.  I need a good solution.

Comment: you can do this by using navigating event See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381492/how-can-i-make-a-wpf-webbrowser-read-only

Comment: Thank you ! navigating event is for webbrowser control 's internal actions,it dosen't work.